# How can I disable Apache Commons / Log4J logging in third party libraries?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons-logging

Is there a Apache Commons / Log4J logging API method which can be used to disable all logging completely, even for loggers which are in third party libraries?

Background: I would like to use java.util.logging in a GlassFish v3 web application. However, a third party library in this web app uses Log4J logging and Apache Commons Logging. To save resources, this logging should be minimized or switched off.

Comment: Does your third party library has a log4j.xml file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit your log4j configuration and set the logging level to ERROR or FATAL

Example for Hibernate:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

This will dwarf the logging output to almost zero, leaving only critical error messages.

Comment: where is the configuration file located or do we have to create and provide one ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just raise the log threshold by package for the external libraries.  I don't know about turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.slf4j.org/

It provides versions of log4j and commons logging libraries that route all the messages to a logging implementation of your choice.